# How can I deploy a gcp API credential via terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I need to deploy a oidc provider to gcp via terraform but can't find what api should I use in this doc https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs.

I can manually deploy it via the console like below screenshot. It has a credential which includes client id and secret. How can I deploy it via terraform and make it output the client id and secret?

[image]

Comment: OAuth 2.0 Client IDs must be created in the Google Cloud Console (or a related site). Google does not offer an API for that feature.

Comment: Does `terraform` support reference the existing resource? like `data xxx`

Comment: Everything must be done in the console. Google does not have public APIs for this feature, therefore Terraform has neither a resource nor a data source.